# SQL Query Error message

Tags: mysql, sql, create-table

I have this SQL Query

```
   CREATE TABLE items(
   partnum VARCHAR( 20 ) NOT NULL ,
   DESC VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
   price INT( 11 ) NOT NULL ,
   src VARCHAR( 25 ) NOT NULL ,
   PRIMARY KEY (  `partnum` )
   );
```

It's meant to create a table in my database but I keep receiving the following error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 price int(11) NOT NULL,
 src varchar(25) NOT NULL,
 ' at line 3
```

Any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Desc is a reserved word (as in `order by foo desc`) and needs to be in back ticks.

Comment: Doh, how did I miss that! @MartinSmith wasn't a duplicate but thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Desc is a reserved keyword it cant used as a name of column,  put it in quotes

or rename it to e.g Description

Comment: putting a keyword in quotes isn't going to solve the problem

Comment: @Ejay I believe it is. HAve you tried it and it fails?

Comment: yes I've tried it. I think you're mixing up _backticks_ and _quotes_ :)